# Pass ng-model value into ng-click failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to pass ng-model's value to ng-click?

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="username">
  <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit(username)">submit</button>
</div>
```

Why in my submit function it doesn't get the username's value?

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26604/

Comment: Did you see your console? `angular.min.js:60 Error: Argument 'TodoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: And you also got typos in your code. `username` and `usernama`.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu if i fix the typo it won't work too

Comment: @EuniceChia your JSFiddle didn't include Angular code at all, only a CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass username as a parameter to your function. You can get the username value from $scope.username in your function already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer:

Corrected the 'username' in `alert` and also while defining the method should not use paranthesis `$scope.submit = function() { }`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function(username){
    alert(username) //get username here
  }
});
```

Also you have specify the module name in the html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
             <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit(username)">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some missings and spelling errors.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function(username){
   alert(username) //get username here
    console.log("username", username)
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app ="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
             <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit(username)">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26607/)**

Comment: Your code works on my localhost but not on my JSFiddle, did I forget to do anything?

Comment: I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26608/). plese check this out. Actually you failed to add `ng-app` name. There were some spelling mistakes etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing decleration of your `ng-app` attribute. Try this:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
```

In addition, correct your function name and argument typo:

```
$scope.submit = function(username){
    alert(username) 
  }
```

Comment: EuniceChia look at the above working fiddle, thanks @jackjop

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code

Below, find the fixed code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
      <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit(username)">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(username){
        alert(userame) //get username here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are errors in your fiddle

please update your submit method as below

```
  $scope.submit = function(username){
    alert(username) //get username here
  }
```

You are using parenthesis () after $scope.submit which is invalid declaration for function.

also give name to ng-app like

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

and  inside alert give variable name properly , you have done spelling mistake in variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of your requirement. Just test on my snippet sending value on `alert()`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.submit = function(mymdl){
  alert(mymdl);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="mymdl"/>
  <button ng-click="submit(mymdl)">Submit</button>
</div>
```